# estimateRigidTransform in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, least-squares

I am using estimateRigidTransform in OpenCV to get the rigid transform matrix
but i do not know how estimateRigidTransform get the rigid transform matrix

Does  estimateRigidTransform use the Least squares Algorithm ?

Answer (score 0):

1) Yes it is uses Least square.

2) You should check [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html#estimaterigidtransform) of function before posting questions here. This is one stackflow requests.

Comment: Thank you.i have checked the documentation before.but i did not find the method estimateRigidTransform ues. it said the function finds an optimal affine transformation :)

Comment: You are welcome. It is saying that estimateRigidTransform finds an optimal affine transformation, but it is also shows the function that is used for definition of what is 'optimal'. This is function of Least Squares.

Comment: are you sure? afair (checked the code some time ago) it uses some kind of RANSAC with fixed/hardcoded parameters. But I'm too lazy to check again... see https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/issues/4270

Comment: @Micka, you are right. Documentation is not describing the calculation correctly. We already had a conversation about this few month after publication of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25375597/what-happens-if-i-give-more-inputs-in-estimaterigidtransform-or-getaffinetransfo